# Best Way to Handle Zero to One (Optional) Foreign Key Relationships in MySql

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, foreign-keys, ado.net-entity-data-model

Not sure if this is possible... however I have a table called "LineItems" with a column called "PackageId" -> PackageId IS optional, however i'd still like to somehow setup a foreign key relationship to its relating table Packages - is this possible? If so how might I go about doing it

Also, I will be using the ADO.net Entity Framework Model v4 in conjunction with MySql. i would like to apply this constraint via MySQL (if possible) and have it carry into the Entity Framework model code

thanks!

Loren

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, however I just learned that by setting a column to allow null appears to allow me to still keep the foriegn key relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for my ignorance, however I just learned that by setting a column to allow null appears to allow me to still keep the foriegn key relationship